# why are images not shown on github for other repos or any image in general?

Tags: image, github

[it just shows the image icon and the link attached to it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQiWW.png)
[it does not load any image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73wfo.png)

I have not tried anything till now cause no one gave a solution for this exact problem. No image is being displayed on github anywhere. I have switched accounts with someone too, no effect. Can someone please help?